# In Agora.io, Which is the function responsible for giving and displaying the output on the Frontend screen?

Tags: agora.io

I have been trying to use Agora.io to implement video calling facility on a website, After setting up the SDK online and attaching the token and channel, How do I display the output video on my website, I am not able to understand how do I display the screen on the website once all Javascript initializations are complete. It would be great if someone could tell me what exactly is the code responsible for the output and how do I style the output to fit in the page with a specific width and height.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have successfully publish your local stream. After that, you need to set up to subscribe to a remote stream. This is how one can catch a video stream and display on your web app.

You can follow the steps here: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/start_call_web?platform=Web#subscribe-to-a-remote-stream